# InApp Purcahse Issue : Why its showing Unresolved Reference: setType for BillingFlowParams?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

Using billing library in android and to buy **subscription** instead of in-app products (consumable-non consumable), added `.setType(SkuType.SUBS)` to `BillingFlowParams` as below :

```
val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
                                    .newBuilder()
                                    .setType(SkuType.SUBS)
                                    .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList!![i])
                                    .build()
```

But, `.setType(SkuType.SUBS)` shows me **Unresolved Reference: setType**

What might be the issue ? **How can I launch Purchase flow for the In-App Subscription**?

Comment: It gives you an error because there's not method called `setType` on `Builder` class. Refer here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder

Comment: But then What if I want to initiate purchase flow for the Subscription instead of In-app Products (consumable-nonconsumable) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS`

You can launch purchase flow like below

```
billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams).getResponseCode();
```

if we go more thoroughly,

-BTW It's in java

first, you have to implement `PurchasesUpdatedListener, AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener` in your class and override `onPurchasesUpdated` and `onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse` methods.

then initialize the billing client

```
private void initBilling() {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this)
                .build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                    billingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, (billingResult1, purchaseHistoryRecordList) -> {
                        Log.i("SKURESLUT", purchaseHistoryRecordList.toString());
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

            }
        });
    }
```

then you can pass the desired package id to the following method and start the billingFlow,

```
private void getBillingPackage(String id) {
        List<String> productIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
        productIdsList.add(id);
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(productIdsList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                (result, skuDetailsList) -> {
                    if (!skuDetailsList.isEmpty()) {
                        mSkuDetails.addAll(skuDetailsList);
                        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                .setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0))
                                .build();
                        int responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParams).getResponseCode();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Requested package not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Log.e("SKURESLUT", result.toString());
                });
    }
```

then in onPurchaseUpdated Method will invoke when billing flow is completed or canceled. You can acknowledge the purchase here

```
@Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                && purchases != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                Log.e("Purchase:", purchase.toString());
                if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                    currentPurchase = purchase;
                    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
                        AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                                AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                                        .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                        .build();
                        billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Handle any other error codes.
        }
    }
```

Then you can get AcknowledgePurchase like below

```
@Override
    public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            //Purchase Acknowledged and verified
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Purchase Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Log.e("Acknowledged Purchase:", billingResult.toString());

    }
```

Comment: What is mSkuDetails ?

Comment: That is the local array list which I keep the list receive from querySkuDetailsAsync. Ignore that

Comment: Got bro. Actually I was doing the same thing but a small mistake was there. By the way Know few new lines of code from your answer. Thanks.

Comment: One question here : Inside onBillingSetupFinished method, We will get the purchases that user has purchased earlier correct ?